# How to enable swiping inside the tab when the swiping for the tabbed page is disabled

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am working on Xamarin.form application, where I have a tabbed page with 2 tabs. Inside the first tab, I have a grid for which I have SwipeGestureRecognizers.

Now, my problem is I have the swipe gesture recognizers which are not even firing as tabbed page swiping is set to false(My assumption).

Is there any way to allow swiping in the child content of the tabbed page for which the swiping is disabled(Tabbed page).

Renderer

```
 public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
    {
        base.OnViewAdded(child);
        var tabLayout = child as TabLayout;
        if (tabLayout != null)
        {
            if(Device.Idiom==TargetIdiom.Phone)
            {
                tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeScrollable;
            }                
        }
    }



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<controls:FloatingTabbedPage
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Inaspect.Controls" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            x:Class="App.Views.TabbedViews">

</controls:FloatingTabbedPage>
```

and I am adding the children from the code behind which are content pages

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#1c2437">
        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Swiped="OnSwipeLeft"/>
            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" Swiped="OnSwipeRight"/>
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

Now, I need to disable the tab changing when I swipes right or left grid.

Comment: Would you post a demo so that we can test it for you?

Comment: Thanks for the response @AbbyWang-MSFT, Could you please look at my update.